# TypeError: Undefined property of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a sorting algo visualizer and i am getting this error(Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')) in line `let bars = this.state.array.map((value, index) =>` here is my code. The whole code at below link error at line(165) : https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y220e1b19

Thanks in Advance

```
render() {
    let bars = this.state.array.map((value, index) => 
    // console.log(`The ${index} is ${ceo}`);
    { 
        return (
        <Bar
            key={index}
            index={index} 
            length={value}
            color={this.state.colorKey[index]}
            changeArray={this.changeArray}
        />
        );
        });
```

Comment: What's the exact error message and which line is it referring to?

Comment: Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at line 165 in linked code

Comment: State variables can be undefined during the first render cycle. Start the render function with `if (!this.state.array) return null;`. By always doing this you'll avoid calling `map()` (or any other function) on undefined variables.

Comment: It's telling you that `this.state.array` is undefined. Why? Share more of your code here on Stack Overflow (not on some other site) and someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Should render be define as?

```
Render = () => {
}
```

If above doesn't help have you put a break point to see which part of

```
this.state.array.map((value, index) =>
```

is undefined?